# Error on use of @array does not match its definition-I used this table without trouble but now in new share latex it shows error

Tags: tables, errors

I'm getting an error on latex. ... The purpose was to create some tables on latex, but it is getting me some error which i don't really understand.Actually,one time I create this table on a latex file without problem, but when I copy it to anther file, It shows error:(  ... Any hint for me please ? Thank you in advance :)

error: use of @array does not match its definition
Argumant of @firstoftwo has an extra }
use of @argtabular cr does not match its definition
missing number treated as zero
Illegal unit od measures (pt inserted)
code:

```
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\centering{}\caption{A brief review of previous studies on the GVRP}
\noindent\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%%
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering}m{2.7cm}|>{\centering}b{2.5cm}|>{\centering}p{2.5cm}|>{\centering}m{2.5cm}|c|}
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Researchers} & {\scriptsize{}Customers\textquoteright{} Management Features} & {\scriptsize{}Stations Features} & {\scriptsize{}Vehicles Features} & {\scriptsize{}Distribution Management Features}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Conrad and Figliozzi 2011~\cite{key-10} } & {*} &  & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Erdogan and Miler-Hooks 2012 ~\cite{key-4} } &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Omidvar and Tavakkoli-Moghadam 2012~\cite{key-11} } & {*} &  & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Schneider et al. 2014~\cite{key-12} } & {*} &  & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Yang and Sun 2015~\cite{key-13} } &  & {*} & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Felipe et al. ~~ ~~ 2014  ~\cite{key-14} } &  & {*} & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}Goeke and Schneider 2015~\cite{key-15}} & {*} &  & {*} & \tabularnewline
\hline 
{\scriptsize{}This research} &  &  &  & {*}\tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome, the snippet is not really useful, you should always post a compilable example to reproduce the exact error. Just to be completly sure, you did load package `array`? Without the package, the syntax used is not allowed.

Comment: Apart from that, the generated table is just awful to look at. The choice of citekeys isn't very good and the way you are doing author and year is very bad. I recommend to read an introduction to LaTeX.

Comment: thanks for you consideration. yes. I add the package "array" but the problem is not solved. maybe it is a problem with Elsevier template. when I add my table in it (i cannot change the format, but thanks for youe comment) , It shows the error : ( I decide to uploud every pakcage in template, maybe it works : (

Answer (score 3):

The column types `m` and `b` are not defined in the LaTeX kernel. They are provided by package `array`, which needs to be loaded:

```
\usepackage{array}
```

Also:

- The font size is *much*, *much* too small.
- Too many lines, see the documentation of package `booktabs`.
- `\centering`, `\scriptsize`, ... are commands without arguments. A simple
  space to end the command name if necessary will do, there is no need for a group (`{}`).
- `\textquoteright` is *not* a apostrophe, the latter is just a simple `'`.
- Tabular cells in latex form already a group, there is no need for an additional pair of braces here, e.g.  `& {*} &` → `& * &`.
- `et al. 2014` has sentence space after the abbreviation `al.`. A normal space is set, if the space factor is reset by `\@`:  `et al.\@ 2014`.

A suggestion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcommand*{\NarrowCell}{%
  \RaggedRight
  \hangafter=1
  \hangindent=1em\relax
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{A brief review of previous studies on the GVRP}
  \small % not smaller than \small
  \def\x#1{\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\NarrowCell}Xcccc}
  \toprule
  Researchers
  & \x{Customers'\\ Management\\ Features}
  & \x{Stations\\ Features}
  & \x{Vehicles\\ Features}
  & \x{Distribution\\ Management\\ Features}
  \tabularnewline
  \midrule
  Conrad and Figliozzi 2011~\cite{key-10}
  & * &   & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Erdogan and Miler-Hooks 2012 ~\cite{key-4}
  &   &   &   & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Omidvar and Tavakkoli-Moghadam 2012~\cite{key-11}
  & * &   & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Schneider et al.\@ 2014~\cite{key-12}
  & * &   & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Yang and Sun 2015~\cite{key-13}
  &   & * & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Felipe et al.\@ 2014~\cite{key-14}
  &   & * & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  Goeke and Schneider 2015~\cite{key-15}
  & * &   & * & \tabularnewline
  \addlinespace
  This research
  &   &   &   & * \tabularnewline
  \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: hello, thanks for your consideration. actually, I do not use latex. I am not able to use it. I use the lyx for creating my code. if i download the array package, I can correct my mistake yes??? moreover, about the size, the table go out of the page when I use another font.:(

Comment: I add the package "array" , but the problem is not solved. it could perhaps be a problem with Elsevier template, could be???. when I add my table in it  , It shows the error. I decide to upload every package in the template, maybe it works.

Comment: It worksssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you so muchhhhhhhhhhhhhh my friend.

Comment: excuse me...i have different error now.

Comment: @arghavansharafi "different error" looks like a new question. This time with a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (minimal, but complete), please.

Comment: excuse me, when I changed the font in Table from tiny to small , the table goes out of page. what can I do?

Comment: @arghavansharafi There are lots of options. It depends on the table. Example: Narrower columns, rotated table headers, a little less space between columns, reorganizing the table, ...